# unable to connect to Zookeeper on localhost:2181

Tags: java, apache-kafka, connection, apache-zookeeper

My application is trying to connect to Zookeeper @ localhost:2181. Zookeeper is running and checked on command prompt. However, when application runs, I am seeing below exception repeatedly :

```
2018-08-06 22:25:09 DEBUG ZkClient:919 - Closing ZkClient...
2018-08-06 22:25:09 INFO  ZkEventThread:82 - Terminate ZkClient event thread.
2018-08-06 22:25:09 DEBUG ZkConnection:77 - Closing ZooKeeper connected to localhost:2181
2018-08-06 22:25:09 DEBUG ZooKeeper:673 - Closing session: 0x0
2018-08-06 22:25:09 DEBUG ClientCnxn:1306 - Closing client for session: 0x0
2018-08-06 22:25:10 INFO  ClientCnxn:975 - Opening socket connection to server localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2018-08-06 22:25:10 DEBUG ClientCnxn:1086 - An exception was thrown while closing send thread for session 0x0 : Connection refused
2018-08-06 22:25:10 DEBUG ClientCnxnSocketNIO:203 - Ignoring exception during shutdown input
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.shutdownInput(SocketChannelImpl.java:780)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.shutdownInput(SocketAdaptor.java:399)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.cleanup(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:200)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.cleanup(ClientCnxn.java:1185)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1122)
2018-08-06 22:25:10 DEBUG ClientCnxnSocketNIO:210 - Ignoring exception during shutdown output
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.shutdownOutput(SocketChannelImpl.java:797)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.shutdownOutput(SocketAdaptor.java:407)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.cleanup(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:207)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.cleanup(ClientCnxn.java:1185)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1122)
2018-08-06 22:25:10 DEBUG ClientCnxn:1290 - Disconnecting client for session: 0x0
2018-08-06 22:25:10 INFO  ZooKeeper:684 - Session: 0x0 closed
2018-08-06 22:25:10 DEBUG ZkClient:932 - Closing ZkClient...done
2018-08-06 22:25:10 INFO  ClientCnxn:512 - EventThread shut down
```

Moreover, in the log, it is saying

```
ClientCnxn:975 - Opening socket connection to server localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
```

It means is it trying to connect localhost.localdomain?

Please help me out to resolve.

Comment: Can you paste your source code?

Comment: @AbhishekN Thank u but I am sorry here to paste the code.

Comment: That's ok, can you try with port 9091 instead of 2181. Seems you are playing with AdminUtils or other intrinsic functions. Try ZkClient zkClient = new ZkClient("localhost:9091", 5000, 5000, ZKStringSerializer$.MODULE$);

Comment: @AbhishekNactually, I can't run thru command line. The Zookeeper and Kafka is started by root. I don't have access to run Zookeeper thru command line. When root run from command line localhost:9092 both producer and consumer recieves messages. The application is also running as root.

Comment: No it's not a command, use that code in your app for creating zookeeper client. I think you may be using some other code (unfortunately can't see what you are doing).

Answer (score 0):

I had also similar problem. I configured below parameter in zoo.cfg(C:\kafka_folder\zookeeper-3.5.4\conf) & the Error disappeared.

```
admin.enableServer=true
admin.serverPort=9990
```

or 
Try this  `ZkClient zkClient = new ZkClient("localhost:9091", 5000, 5000, ZKStringSerializer$.MODULE$);`

People are also getting this error in ***kafka-unit or kafka-junit*** (Integration tests).In this case you have to use   kafka-client dependency version 1.0.2(other versions are not supporting for ***kafka-unit or kafka-junit***).

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```